# updating JUST HTML files on Google App Engine

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine, ftp

I have a Google App Engine Application, and as part of that Application I have my standard HTML pages, Home, ContactUs, Testimonials, Pricing ETC ETC, when users click on "login" or go to a specific URL eg (`www.diarybooker.com/demo`) it loads the actual application.

All these standard HTML files are fairly static files though, with analytics and SEO etc in them, however in order to update these currently I need to release a new version of my application every time.

Can anyone offer any advice as to how I can JUST update the HTML without having to release a new version of my application (especially if I am in the middle of a development cycle and don't want to branch just to update a contact number or fix an SEO issue etc)

It is entirely possible that I am actually using the system incorrectly and that I should be re-wiring things better/differently, but I cant find any information about how this SHOULD be setup, and Im not even sure what to search for either, so if anyone can at least point me in the direction of some information on this, I would be very greatful!!

By way of an alternative example, I have a friend who is running `www.wineathome.org.uk` and if you click on "attend a tasting" it moves off into `http://wineathomeuk.appspot.com`. Clearly this is not very clean and is also not the way to make it work, I could embed the application in an iframe, but is that really the way to go?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your application code in source control, right? I'd suggest that you create a deployment directory and clone into it the version of the application that you want to have running on AppEngine. Then, copy into the deployment directory the versions of the HTML files that you want updated. Deploy away.

That is the only strategy that's going to work for you. The GAE deployment tool only deals with your application as a whole.

Comment: Actually its not in source control as I don't know how to use source control, so if you have some kind of "dummys guide" somewhere that makes it REALLY easy to understand to to make it work, without me needing to spend hours figuring it out then I would be happy to hear it. Currently I just use a manual source control process: zip up each version as I release it and back up both in the cloud and on external disks...
(I have tried looking at several free source control options, but gave up as it was taking too much time and effort to figure it out)

Comment: @johnvdenley, I'd suggest reading Joel Spolsky's hginit.com as an excellent introduction to both Mercurial -- a good, modern Distributed Version Control System -- and the principles of purposes of source control.

Comment: What about github, have heard a lot of suggestions that I should be using that!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a couple of issues going on.

On the first issue as @AdamCrossland states you can use source control.  I use git and create branches for my application at different versions.  If you do that you can merge your updated HTML back into an older branch then update your application from that branch.  That way your only changing the HTML files and leaving the application in it's current state.  App Engine deploy is intelligent and will only upload the modified files.  Doing this from Eclipse is a bit more difficult than from the CLI IMO, but YMMV.

The other issue of a friend clicking on attend a tasting routing the url to appspot is a bit harder to deal with unless some code is provided.  I would think it is because the code is doing a redirect to a hard coded URL.  I have several application mapped to a domains and none of them route to appspot unless I forced it to in order to use some functionality like HTTPS which only works on appspot.com.  I personally try to avoid iframes it opens up an avenue for exploits.

Comment: When you say "mapped to a domains" do you mean the whole application is mapped (just like I have already done with DiaryBooker.com)?